# MaterializeCSS : How to Toggle 2 Notifications When Pressing One button (On and Off)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I put my Personal Website at this Link
[StyleSource-Library BETA](http://cxlink.tk)

While Working at some contents. I Created A Container Enabler/Disabler Button.
 In The Navigation Bar On Right on The Top Position
The Button Works Perfectly for adding container class to the `div` tag. I also made something that makes the user know if the container class is activated or not. But the problem is that it doesn't work or They Show the same notification like `Container is ON` when pressed twice (Its should be `Container is ON` and `Container is OFF`) or It end up Giving An Error in Console Like `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` and `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )` But first,Here's the code for activating the container.

**HTML**

```
<li>
    <a href="#" id="ToggleContainer-NoficationStatus" class="tooltipped toggle-container waves-effect waves-red" data-position="bottom" data-delay="100" data-tooltip="Iam a Container Adder-Disabler :)">
        <i class="material-icons">web</i>
    </a>
</li>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.toggle-container').click(function(){
        $('#adder').toggleClass('container');
    });
</script>
```

> And For activating the Notification but it actually not showing or
>   showing an error Here's the code for Toggling The Notification when
>   the Container Class Is detected or not in `div` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ToggleContainer-NoficationStatus").click(function() {
            $(#adder).hasClass("container");
            setTimeout(function() {
                Materialize.toast('Container Layout is On.', 2000);
            }, 500);
        });
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ToggleContainer-NoficationStatus").click(function() {
            (!$(#adder).hasClass("container"));
            setTimeout(function() {
                Materialize.toast('Container Layout is Off.', 3000);
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="adder" class=""> //This is where the Container Class Goes on
```

I have been working on this feature 3 hours ago and still can't move on and can't find any solution out there in the internet. Even though there has but it doesn't work. My Mother is getting angry for staying out for 12 hours in computer working on some my personal project.
I need some help :) I Mean how to fix this error?  Any help is appreciated. :)

**INFO**
To Find out wheres the error actually happen. Please Go to my web [StyleSource-Library BETA](http://cxlink.tk/index.html) the error is in the button at top right section. The Icon is Like Web Layout Icon.

Comment: First checking through typo error, i would point quotes left at two places in your script code. **Add quotes** to `$("#adder")` in your script code.

Comment: @divy3993 Thanks for replying. :) The Notification Showed Up but theres another problem. When the container class is activated. The notification showed up as The Container Layout is ON. But when I turn it off. It says the Same (<code>Container Layout is ON</code>). Note that I also made the script that also for "When turning off the container class". That was also my problem on the time I post it here. (I just changed the code before posting though)

Comment: Did you updated it live?

Comment: Ok posted the Answer just check out. If still need help, feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes, The Web is updated right now. Please see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With considering your comments, posting the answer. Updated your Script as needed to **make your script more simpler and efficient**.

```js
$('.toggle-container').click(function(){
 // Step 1: It would toggle class at begin
    $('#adder').toggleClass('container');
    
    // Step 2: Would check if '#adder' has class=conatiner and displays toast, if not goes to Step 3
    if($("#adder").hasClass("container")) 
        {
         alert("Container Layout is ON"); // Write your setTimeout function here.
        }
    
    //Step 3:  Would check if '#adder' does not has class=conatiner and displays toast.
    if(!$("#adder").hasClass("container")) 
    {
        alert("Container Layout is OFF"); // Write your setTimeout function here.
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><a href="#" id="ToggleContainer-NoficationStatus" class="tooltipped 
toggle-container waves-effect waves-red" data-position="bottom" 
data-delay="100" data-tooltip="Iam a Container Adder-Disabler :)">
<i class="material-icons">web</i></a></li>


<div id="adder" class=""> //This is where the Container Class Goes on</div>
```

To try with modifications a Demo Link below:

[JSFiddle : DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w9cq5ctk/2).

[Fiddle : Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/w9cq5ctk/3/)

Comment: Looks like the Materialize.css is not added to the snippet. Btw. Will try this. And I dont think calling a alert would call the notification. But still will try as i can. :) Will check the scripts you made.

Comment: @CodexLink Just replace line `alert(.....);`  with your **`setTimeout `** Funcrions.

Comment: @CodexLink No it's not added,  `alert` is just to give you explanation.

Comment: Oh ok thanks. I thought the alert your telling is about showing it in tab. or Something like Confirmation or something. But anyways would try again

Comment: Ok what I did is this
`setTimeout(function() {
          Materialize.toast("Container Layout is ON"); 3000);
    }, 1000;`
Did it like this and the Toast doesnt showed up or the Notification.
Yes. I changed the `alert` to `Materialize.toast` and I also add the Timer but I guess I did the right way. Also theres a problem that it gives an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )`

Comment: You have mistakes in terminating the brackets of setTimeout func. and if loop.

Comment: Thank you very much dude. Just To clarify that I My Code Has A Bracket Problems. Thanks to you again. To Clarify The People that wants the view this topic Please post your code from Jsfiddle. Or I will post it? I give credit to you dude to the about page section of my page.
Summarization
Update your post with your codes in Jsfiddle and Will prove it check. :)
Cheers :D

Comment: Glad that it helped you. Thanks. :) My Fiddle is already updated in the Answer. Are you asking me to update with `setTimeout` code?

Comment: @CodexLink Updated the Fiddle.

Comment: What I mean is update your post with fixed Code. :) That you provide above. :D So I could declare that I approved your post :) I can't post my self because I'm not the one who fixed the code but you are.